# How to notify different channels in Datadog for renotification

Tags: monitor, datadog

I am using a Datadog monitor to alert in my slack channel (let's call it channel-one). Now there are renotifications for the same monitor but I don't want to send the renotification to the same channel but to a different channel (let's call it channel-two) and not to channel-one. I tried to add channel-two in the {{#is_renotify}} but then it is also alerting to channel-one which is not what I want. Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this?

{{#is_alert}}
alert to @channel-one
{{/is_alert}}

{{#is_renotify}}
renotify alert to @channel-two
{{/is_renotify}}